# Setting textarea programmatically doesn't work C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, geckofx

Trying to set textare with code but it doesnot work, I already set input fields and working fine without any problems.

```
GeckoElementCollection TextAreaCollection = 
    geckoWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea");

foreach (GeckoElement textArea in TextAreaCollection)
{
    string textAreaName = textArea.GetAttribute("name");
    if (textAreaName == "message")
    {
        ((GeckoHtmlElement)textArea).Focus();
        // ((GeckoHtmlElement)textArea).SetAttribute("value", selectedAD.description);
        ((GeckoHtmlElement)textArea).TextContent = selectedAD.description;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set the focus on that element to fill in the value.
And instead of casting the object to GeckoHtmlElement, cast it to GeckoTextAreaElement and set the Value property.

`(textArea as GeckoTextAreaElement).Value = "Something, something, something, Dark Side';`

Hope this helps:)